# Is there any way to shape the submit button of the HTML form?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I'm Creating a html page with forms. in that I want to shape my submit button to look like an arrow like below (not exactly below, i'm expecting just 2D arrow)...

[image]

Is there any way to do that...

Comment: use background image...

Comment: yes we can use background image, but still the button looks in rectangular shape. I want to shape it...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/s5vvdnqu/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Revanth_Rev/bcq898mb/1/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in css something like this but add your own sizes, and to apply submit button to this you simply add this HTML above or below your submit button in your form and then just position submit button over this arrow and make it transparent by adding opacity: property to your submit button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#triangle{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 100px solid red;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
margin: 100px;
}
#square{
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
margin: -20px 0 0 -200px;
background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="triangle"><div id="square"></div></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use svg graphics in html5.
The HTML  element (introduced in HTML5) is a container for SVG graphics.

SVG has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and graphic images.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested using background image then you can use like this:

```
button{
   background: transparent url(shape.jpg) no-repeat;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   width: 250px; /*img width*/
   height: 350px; /*img height*/
}
```

Comment: Actually this works fine... but, it is still clickable around the arrow (i mean top-left and bottom-left ). because this code just hides the background and make them transparent. But, I'm asking about shaping the button to clickable only in the arrow. not around the spaces...